# how to access nested array

Tags: api

how can I access the values in a nested array, e.g. when using get for contact entity
e.g. how can I adjust the following to get the first name? (not working for me at the moment)

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Contact', 'get', array(
   'sequential' => 1,
   'return' => array("first_name", "last_name", "email"),
   'id' => 28296
));
echo $result['values'][0]['first_name'];
```

if I use var_dump ($result) I get the following so the results are there:

array(5) { ["is_error"]=> int(0) ["version"]=> int(3) ["count"]=> int(1) ["id"]=> int(28296) ["values"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(6) { ["contact_id"]=> string(5) "28296" ["first_name"]=> string(8) "Thirteen" ["last_name"]=> string(4) "Test" ["email_id"]=> string(5) "27750" ["email"]=> string(25) "thirteen.test@artigma.com" ["id"]=> string(5) "28296" } } }

thanks much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use something like $contactData = $result['values'][0] for your var_dump to test. Your echo should be right, in theory.

Comment: Also, getSingle may be useful to you:

`$result = civicrm_api3('Contact', 'getsingle', array(
  'sequential' => 1,
  'last_name' => "Tobias",
  'first_name' => "Randy",
  'id' => 4,
));`

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction, guys. This did the trick:

$contactData = $result['values'][0]['contact_id'];
echo "Contact ID: " . $contactData;